# IBM Worklight - Facing error message when using function navigator.notification.alert

Tags: cordova, ibm-mobilefirst

I want to show an alert message. For this I amm using `navigator.notification.alert("Username or Password is not correct.",null, "Login Failed", "OK")`, but this is not working.

I get an error message:

> "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'alert' of undefined".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. It seems to me you are previewing the "Common" environment in Worklight Console. This will not work there because this code snippet requires Cordova, whereas in Common you do not have Cordova.

   To make this work, you must preview this code in an environment, such as Android.
   Add the Android environment to your application in Worklight Studio and re-build and deploy it. Then in Worklight Console preview the Android environment and you will see your alert.
2. Since you are using Worklight, I recommend using the [Worklight-provided API](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wrklight/v5r0m6/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.worklight.help.doc/apiref/r_wl_simpledialog_show.html) `WL.SimpleDialog`.

The API method `WL.SimpleDialog.show` will allow you to create a dialog that will use the native UI components of each environment it will be invoked at (this includes Common).

```
WL.SimpleDialog.show(
    "Error",
     "Username or Password is not correct. Login failed.", 
     [{
         text: "OK", handler: function() {WL.Logger.debug("'OK' button tapped."); }
     }]
);
```

Comment: Thanks this helps. can i also append the css on this dialog box?

Comment: Only in environments that a native dialog is not being provided for them: Common, BlackBerry 6/7, Mobile Web. In Mobile environments (Android, Windows Phone 7.5/8, iOS, BlackBerry 10) it is a native dialog, so CSS is not part of it.

Comment: What is the environment you are targeting?

Comment: I am targeting Android, iPhone and Mobile Web.

Comment: @Rajiv, For Mobile Web you can customize the appearance of the dialog by overriding the following CSS IDs: WLdialogContainer, WLdialogOverlay, WLdialog, WLdialogTitle, WLdialogBody, WLdialog button. You can see the current style properties for these IDs in wlclient.css